# EmEditorで括弧に続く単語の最初の文字を大文字に変換するには

Tags: emeditor

以下のような文を選択して

**norwegian wood (this bird has flown)**

「編集→選択範囲の変換→単語の最初の文字を大文字に変換」を実行すると

**Norwegian Wood (this Bird Has Flown)**

となり、括弧後の**this**の語頭が大文字になりません。

現在はやむなく置換で括弧後にスペースを入れ、「～大文字に変換」を実行後
再度置換で当該スペースを削除することで望む結果を得ていますが、
あまりスマートではありませんので、なにか良い方法や設定、たとえば
「括弧を語頭と見なす/見なさない」ようなオプションがありましたら
ご教示いただきたく思います。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> で [置換] ダイアログを表示し、[正規表現] をチェックして、

[検索する文字列] `\b\w`

[置換後の文字列] `\U\0`

と入力して [すべて置換] ボタンをクリックしてください。すると、上のサンプルは、

```
Norwegian Wood (This Bird Has Flown)
```

と変換されます。